# Outline span inside div separately on hover

Tags: jquery

I have a div element and, inside it, a span with some text in it. I need to add an outline class to the element when a mouse hovers over each element.

It seems to work when I start on a div and then move to the span, but not the other way around. If I am on a span -- it is outlined, but if I move mouse from it to div, the outline on span goes away, as intended, but the outline over the div does not appear.

Here's what I've got:

**CSS**

```
.outline {
    outline: 5px solid #66ff66;
}
```

**JS**

```
function divColor() {
    $('.myDiv').hover(
        function() {
            $('.outline').removeClass('outline');
            $(this).attr('title', 'Change background').addClass('outline');             
        },
        function () {
            $(this).attr('title', '').removeClass('outline');
        }
    );
}

function textColor() {
    $('.myText').hover(
        function() {
            $('.outline').removeClass('outline');
            $(this).attr('title', 'Change color').addClass('outline');              
        },
        function() {
            $(this).attr('title', '').removeClass('outline');
        }
    );
}

$('.myDiv, .myText').mousemove(function(){
    divColor();
    textColor();            
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="myDiv">
    <span class="myText">some text</span>    
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe I am not reading your question correctly, but couldn't you achieve this using only CSS?

Comment: He probably could and should. And a jsFiddle would've been welcomed.

Comment: Just use the :hover CSS pseudoclass

Comment: I use jQuery because I need to select elements to do some DOM manipulation in addition to indicating which one I am hovering over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some JS in your CSS block, also I don't think you need to track mousemove, you can just bind to the hover function. I.e. use this JavaScript:

```
$('.myText').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).mouseIn = true;           
    },
    function() {
        $(this).attr('title', '').removeClass('outline');
        $('.myDiv').addClass('outline');
    }
);

$('.myDiv').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).attr('title', 'Change background').addClass('outline');             
    },
    function () {
        $(this).attr('title', '').removeClass('outline');
    }
);
```

([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpaceDog/UBdNc/))

The problem with mousemove is that it's attached to those elements so it doesn't get called when you're outside those elements (which is needed to remove the class). Either you'd have to track all mouse movements on a container div which is overkill or do something like this:

```
function mouseIn() {
    $(this).data('mouseIn', true);
}

function mouseOut() {
    $(this).data('mouseIn', false);
    $(this).removeClass('outline'); 
}

$('.myDiv').hover(mouseIn, mouseOut);
$('.myText').hover(mouseIn, mouseOut);

$('.myDiv, .myText').mousemove(function(){
    if ($('.myDiv').data('mouseIn')) {
        // Mouse is in the div
        if ($('.myText').data('mouseIn')) {
            // Mouse is in the span
            $('.myDiv').removeClass('outline');
            $('.myText').addClass('outline');
        } else {
            // In the div but not the span
            $('.myDiv').addClass('outline');
            $('.myText').removeClass('outline');            
        }
    } 
    // No else as the span is contained in the div, otherwise the 
    // else clause would mean mouse is in the span. Since this is 
    // only called when it's inside one or other (or both) 
});
```

([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpaceDog/Jmnr5/))

**Edit**

In your comment you look for a more generic way, if we create a class 'raiseable' to define things that we can outline/raise, then we could try and do something clever with switching the class off in the parents. However, this relies on the hover events happening in the right order. The code looks like:

```
function mouseIn() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('outline'); 
    $(this).addClass('outline'); 
}

function mouseOut() {
    $(this).removeClass('outline');     
}

$('.raiseable').hover(mouseIn, mouseOut);
```

([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpaceDog/wBWcz/))

However, as you can see from that the hover events don't always happen in the right order so we can't rely on that.

We can use that logic, and the previous logic of adding something to indicate where the mouse is. Instead of adding a data element we'll add another class to indicate where the mouse is as it's easier to work with later. Then we can go through each `raiseable` class and see if it has children with `hasMouse` if it does then it doesn't get outlined and the loop will eventually outline the last element that has the mouse but doesn't have children that have the mouse.

The code looks like:

```
function mouseIn() {
    $(this).data('mouseIn', true);
    $(this).addClass('hasMouse');
}

function mouseOut() {
    $(this).removeClass('hasMouse');
    $(this).data('mouseIn', false);
    // Still need to remove the outline class as 
    // mousemove may not be triggered outside the elements
    $(this).removeClass('outline');
}

$('.raiseable').hover(mouseIn, mouseOut);

$('.container').mousemove(function(){

    var best = null;
    $('.raiseable').each( function() { 

        // Count the number of children with the class 
        // 'hasMouse'. 
        if (($(this).children('.hasMouse').length == 0) && 
            ($(this).data('mouseIn'))) { 
            best = $(this);
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('outline');
        }
    });
    if (best) {
        $(best).addClass('outline');
    }                         
});
```

New HTML:

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class="raiseable">
        <span class="raiseable">some text</span>   
        <span class="raiseable padded">
            <span class="raiseable">some other text</span>    
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

New CSS:

```css
.outline {
    outline: 5px solid #66ff66;
}

.padded {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

([Final Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpaceDog/pASUW/))

It's very possible there's a much more elegant way to do this, or something already built in that I've missed. But that seems to work, I'm sure you can adapt it from there to do whatever you want.

Comment: This is great. I'm trying to think of an even more generic way to do the outline, because I'm not sure what other potential elements I may need to highlight. Is there a way to highlight a top layer elements, when I hover over. Let's say this example, if I hover over div, but not span -- it will be the top layer. But if i move over to span, it becomes the top layer. All I need is to be able to indicate the elements by their selectors, which ones I can apply the outline on. Is there a way to do something like that?

Comment: Hmmm, are all your elements contained within each other (i.e. nested, or at different nesting levels). I think you could do something clever with detecting properties, parents and children. If I come up with something concrete I can add it

Comment: I came up with a couple of different ways of doing it and added them to my answer. Hopefully one of them should be adaptable to what you want.

Comment: No problem, I admit I had a lot of fun working that out. Hope it's useful for you.